# Header background change when scroll down in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

In my wordpress site, I want to fix the header background color only when i scroll the page..
Before I scroll, it look like normal on the content image..

[image]

Can you see this picture, the header background color is visible on image.. what i want is only when i scroll the page this background color will be visible.. before scroll, the header would be look like an content on image..

I used javascript for that below,

```
$(function() {
    $(window).on("scroll", function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop() > 0) {
            $(".site-header").addClass("active");
        } else {

           $(".site-header").removeClass("active");
        }
     });
    });
```

and i used css for this is,

```
.active { background-color: #353535;}
```

but still its not working..

Comment: Can you give a bit more information. Do you mean a sticky header? https://css-tricks.com/scroll-fix-content/

Comment: Can anyone suggest what I do for that??